# Using Variables Passing Into MSSQL Stored Proc as part of queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to use the value from variables that is passed into the stored proc. Is that allow?

For example, I want to pass CID=5,SID=4 Into an Update Stored Proc

and it looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Update @CID nvarchar(4),@SID nvarchar(4)
AS

DELETE FROM [User"+@CID+@SID+"] 

GO;
```

In which is like "DELETE FROM [User54]"

But I want to dynamically done given the parameter

Can it be done and how is it done?

Thanks

Comment: Stored procedures are different for different SQL servers. Please tag your question with relevant server brand: Oracle. MSSQL, Postgres or whichever.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm using MSSQL 2019

Comment: Be careful!! Parameter values like <51, 4> and <5, 14> will result in the same "name". Is that really what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use dynamic SQL.  To do it safely, ensure the created object name is properly delimited using the [quotename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?msclkid=cd5d41d4cfe511ec95c80eb8f5278178&view=sql-server-ver15) function.

Like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateSomeTable @CID nvarchar(4), @SID nvarchar(4)
AS
begin
    declare @tableName nvarchar(500) = quotename(concat('User',@CID,@SID));
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('DELETE FROM ',@tableName);

    --print @sql
    exec sp_executesql @sql 
end
```

Comment: ah, by using by declaring variable, Thanks!